# Global Constructors in Virtual Address Space

Tags: assembly, linker, linker-errors

Following Code in linker.ld:

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf64-x86-64)
ENTRY(start)

HVMA = 0xFFFFFF0000000000;

SECTIONS
{
    . = 1M;
    _start = . + HVMA;

    .init :
    {
        *(.initl)
    }

    . += HVMA;

    .text ALIGN(0x1000) : AT(ADDR(.text) - HVMA)
    {
        *(.inith)
        *(.text)
    }

    .data ALIGN(0x1000) : AT(ADDR(.data) - HVMA)
    {
        start_ctors = .;
        *(.ctor*)
        end_ctors = .;
        start_dtors = .;
        *(.dtor*)
        end_dtors = .;
        *(.data)
    }

    .rodata ALIGN(0x1000) : AT(ADDR(.rodata) - HVMA)
    {
        *(.rodata)
    }

    .bss ALIGN(0x1000) : AT(ADDR(.bss) - HVMA)
    {
        _sbss = .;
        *(COMMON)
        *(.bss)
        _ebss = .;
    }

    _end = .;
}
```

Now when i try to compile everything with -mcmodel=large and then link it with this linker script, i get "relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32S against symbol `end_ctors` defined in .data section in bin/kernel.elf" and the same for `end_ctors`.
I have no idea why. Can i somehow also set it to use 64-bit addresses? -mcmodel=large should cover this, shouldn't it?

Comment: If you have answered your own question, that is great! However, please make the answer an actual answer instead of an edit into your question. This way, other people quickly know that the question has been answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by using:

```
mov r8, end_ctors
cmp rbx, r8
```

instead of:

```
cmp rbx, end_ctors
```

And the same for end_dtors.